# getline cin ignoring first number from input

Tags: c++

I am learning C++ now and I am currently trying to get input using cin and getline. However getline is somehow ignoring the numbers from the input. I have tried placing cin.clear() and cin.ignore() but the problem persists. Is there something I am doing incorrectly?

Here is my code:

```
string test;
int main()
{
    std::cout << "Please enter a date: ";
    std::cin >> test;
    std::getline(std::cin, test);
    cout << test << endl;
}
```

Here is the output:

```
Please enter a date: 1 January 2015
 January 2015
Press any key to continue . . .
```

Comment: So why the downgrades without comment here?  The question is clear.  Grammer is reasonably good, (yes, the title can use a bit of capitalization help.) code clearly written as code.  For those of us learning C/C++ its helpful to see opportunities for improvement.  It doesn't appear to be a homework assignment.  Seems well within the guidelines on what questions to ask on StackOverflow.  So, why the downvotes?  What am I missing?

Comment: @zipzit Simply using a debugger or printing `test` to the console in between the reads would have shown what the problem was.

Comment: Er, no.  DsAjw did exactly that.  He printed test to the console. He didn't get the results he expected. That showed him that there was a problem, but it doesn't remotely address WHY that problem occurred.  I'm still baffled by the downvotes.  over 1/3rd of the folks reading this problem have voted to downgrade this question.  I thought it reasoned and well stated. (but what do I know, sigh...)  He clearly asked "Is there something I am doing incorrectly?"

Comment: @MikeCAT Thanks for the answer, it worked after i removed the std::cin, I was not aware that I was actually trying to get input twice.

Comment: @zipzit I guess the folks here only want to see the really difficult questions. Thanks anyway

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply don't use `std::cin` unless you want to read something.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using std::string;
using std::cout;
using std::endl;

int main()
{
    string test; // Don't use global variable unless it is necessary.
    std::cout << "Please enter a date: " << std::flush;
    // std::cin >> test; // remove this harmful line
    std::getline(std::cin, test);
    cout << test << endl;
    cout << "Press any key to continue . . ." << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`getline` doesn't append. You're reading in to the string until it hits whitespace, then overwriting it with the rest of the line.

```
std::cin >> test; //test == "1"
std::getline(std::cin, test); //test == " January 2015"
```

Comment: So... what's the recommended code?  You've showed us what's wrong, but what's the right way to do this?

Comment: @zipzit I don't know what you're trying to do. Why are you reading in with `>>` and then `getline`? If you just use `getline`, you won't be deleting the first input.

Comment: I'm not trying to do anything.  I'm an innocent bystander.  I too am improving my skills, and I'd like to know how to do this one... I think its clear.  What code is required to get the complete user entry into `cout << test << endl;`   Oops.  I see @MikeCAT directly has answered my question.